# Send data from one JSP file to another using Maven and Jetty

Tags: java, maven, jsp, servlets, jetty

I'm working on a form project which gets an ID from user input (HTML form on a JSP file) and calls another JSP file which processes this ID inside a Java class. This class prints a report for this ID.

How can I send this ID from the 1st JSP file to the 2nd one using servlets on Maven and Jetty?

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When including a JSP file into another, you can use `jsp:param` to include parameters you need in your inner JSP from the parent.

Source: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19575-01/819-3669/bnajd/index.html